# Accessing SD Card Card Specific Registers ( CSR ) data through C++ or C#

Tags: c#, c++, hardware

Hope someone can help, i've been looking through the forums and cant find an appropriate 'hardware' forum...

I have a sat nav, which will only work with the original OEM supplied SD card, and just out of sheer curiousity, ( and also the desire to create a personal backup ), i'm trying to figure out what is different between the OEM card, and brand 'x' with the EXACT same data ( even a 1:1 clone of the card ).

I'm experienced with C#, however, I know the issues with hardware access, so looking at C++, which i'm not quite as hot with. I figure that the difference between the cards must sit in the CIR ( Card Information Register ) or CSR ( Card Specific Register ).

Is there an easy way to pull these from an SD Card in C++ ?

Comment: I suspect if I don't do it, somebody else will come along and ask: "What have you tried so far?".

Comment: To be honest, the furthest I've got is analysing the card via tools like WinHex, etc but they dont seem to be able to provide that level of detail. In all fairness, I expect someone to come along and shoot me down over this question, but if you don't ask, you dont get !